# Unable to login by Opera password manager

Tags: discussion, login

Not sure if this is the right place for this question but anyway I used to use build in Opera password manager to log into my StackOverflow account anytime I access its pages. It worked well but last week it stops.

- I tried to clear/reset Opera password manager
- update Opera
- like all the tips with similar issues suggest with no luck of getting this work

Has something changed in login scripts for SO/SE sites ?

- how can I get this to work again?
- is there some link coding that allows my browser to login directly via url address?
- or I have to install some login robot?

Comment: Might be an http/https issue.

Comment: You might browse the recent [login questions on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=login%20) to see if there is something that might match your setup....

Comment: Hmm just have somehow get it to work the harder way (click login, then CTRL+Enter) that work now (no idea why not before)... but before it all was done automatically without any further clicking

Comment: Just now it start working again as before (1 hour ago it was not working) meanwhile I did nothing

Comment: I assume the unicorns got their waffles fed and now all is good...

Comment: @rene something like that :) had tried everything I could think of for a week and finally when I do nothing it works :)